# What kind of coding language is this?

Tags: coding-style

I viewed the source on a picture on google and this is what I saw this is the first 10 lines what coding language is this???

```
ÿØÿÛC

    



ÿÛCÿÀü°"ÿÄÿÄJ!1A"Qaq#2B‘¡R±Á$3bÑðráñC‚’%4S¢²sÂÒ5cD³âÿÄÿÄ9!1Að"Qaq¡2‘±ÁÑáñ#B3Rb$CrÒÿÚ?á½E%8Y™*‘bŠÈ]IIX¯u«÷nåˆñà
¤Q£
vIc+$—¶mÜÕŽn¬]F¹y¥tuŒ$¡w2ÿ•O`v(¿xìÃŸ%@±'D±  4Q NÞoëÉòœ•pdrXL¦Kšt¡Ó$B’=æÅ_4|#–ÂFÂdŒÌ.†âÅš‰ýCÀ(žükEñD+ˆ]ÞÃ#8­œžoú?Ò´@«T%bWr”Ñ%-¸çëÇù×CRÓ1jEY‡+äC`Øæ˜º31àH@4oÀNÅdÏu6‡nÕävúÕë_=¶æÃ,íL«%Pùòkãï¥Ý2ÆZT¨œu
°#çÁýüiå&Ófxáð*ha—k,    ±kV÷á{_Ïì5içxÂõ`Š™¶$ÊÁù¸Ö–f6R)2q%h6Ø(ºµÕ‘ûéHe‹&) ÂÃYÞRÊÝuö¶ïÖ×s_×Sø’onÒ¾^o"É€‚i‹¬‡+Œ§pVQa€'°ã¾ƒÈc¥ö˜Ïæt€@I&öòxúý4fÅü3¼ÑzzC,Dn,«¹”Ð»ì|Q¯¾š\Y2'=DÚ³Ür±òöòCÀ¹ýõÉ¥Qãåûøž[ü…q²g˜†êÄ¡àe3Å¸)°ã±ÿ]5"*x’XÕ™,«jX  n¨ßíªt%É9ÒY½Œ}¾Õ®nón4÷C¤ä§åª{Yd<¸=Ç~ÄøñGKñe\~}ÐV”yïù3?
”›dXãQ×#4¡B• Gõv<:ˆ&Îê4ªð”7¶W—›ú<v<i¯Ê(ÈÂ7vºmîÛÀæÏ=ˆ=ïL4òLë,£–:V".B×=ûhÇÄUÅ~§=+VÑŽ«VZ¬Â&ž@Â8ö°ï`ŽGôäiXäX$ê
UÞŽ(€+ÏnúÝ†'|¬‚†jBÀ¿›¿¾ƒ“Ò#M$ŠÓ•ÿì×h"ùì>§ë=»šÏ¯ò+ÓJT'•úG­{yÚîìnÉ/"y³¨@  b¬­Ï@¯¥kÂxO[!r'Þ px"Í_Üh¯†ò;‰7K¸t6øã·ß#ñ;•4:ÐH\J2ÉleÇ‡±2H¢GØøìu›'§Ç“Y²£ŠX‰"`üƒüµÛç[àÑ­¬‘Û1$¸–*9ó`wñÎ§K4B>0ˆÕÅÒÊå<ÐýÆê¹, ¨F<3°Œ8Ê“Ì"‘Ô#Ì¬Ê¦ù=üwýµŒc;ÌÑ°k•G°÷"¾µÛûë ü“‹õA&CäHÆE–q[«s;hGÞÆ¦|x¶Í²XCvS`_ž;Q¯ë¤n2èÂa¦:ºÄ0ÝVZèvý¯ˆ…Ú6XQHì§s1ðÿmk•Ç‹*G@RI(+j<yìH ýõ°ÁCFÉX]T‚{ƒc½ð4­µ£°ò)øty:Š‡ÞNâ!°,úI²EPã‹Õ×¤Êî˜¥ªœpYqûwúi©/Ì+$²þ­>å¡Á¿¹=µ2DÒ$¢ É¹‡I¸>,vïÜêºNU’sQ±4Xõa =E’¢~(qýt–T(dsG›Í«¡+ ø³ú[]c1Îó0“aÝ·iÚÍè)7á–yö™«¨WuSÿnçK¶ÞÖ5%M÷ö0¥…æ|vÆ–%u$©ëÀ(ƒ\ø?¾½›\Œ›u,C6âÛ4 >¦·áð’¡ÉüÆPH”À±ä~yâûýt) Y8™a¥h2­†Mqü¦þ/),Ø)psð‡‰2B:×`Ôlž>lÞˆ    TFC•ÔgŽÝ¬P#’|?jÙcÂ­<õ­
‘ÍyJ|ò+ãNäúvC0^¶FL.—{—Ž=¼ŽàÙûìAÔæùä¶Õ¶ÌUXvÉH´@AÞ}òú@7_»éY£DÈ!È–w_§  î9þaÇöÖöf6×TQ»ÚA4n…öâ‰:Mp°ft…HŠÀpûœ°#¿Çï§SÚÈí¿‘Œ yHdŠÊ##tdØw3º;—ÚASæŽþÓÊâ2ÊŠ©ÓÞ¿añçZ>£K$R4g')£€–Â#‹¾8÷ñ§’f\‚‘*²4e‹¢‚lùø#úh)B×êçIPáÃ“ŠÓ“Û¹w;+ÜEçúúög¥ÈòÆþœ­øqî¬X>îA=¼tï™!1¤e™ŒjYA¯Ö¨ß'èt
ç/rŽ™ºij¶nú~ÚyÃ9FIY‰£ÌT¼ð3/pÃ2€mCÜ“gú

½<uYLRx!‰Û÷#‚u¹¬™]U‹Šjv;G€<w°ÛTš    ]¢fË:š ‚/ŽàWÛÇÎ©ÿ&êŽZO6eË‚Ë‰NÆDîXp°M÷?O4+LÂÎ<ŽØð¬ˆ%1NA'ÿw‘uØÿ}Á!:I1v~þ›
£`_I¯Š:}@IæŽZI.Žñ¸…%¾þ?¦™j)u 8cW!™à„ªƒrHB   |(5Êó}»ý´œ±ˆ}2º£`Ç½Ê„Q+ú~çiÔˆÙgxI¡°
€§ÉïzôÆ‹H€68` 7>ÁíÜGoþ©Gë€=;fdp¯âB´å£tVS"6px†&LM«;Z@ò6ÑMôç›þÚÒ@xYzl‰½Aàƒ}ÅŽ{>š2)l¡'ED.ºŠá¬–ÿßèu’nŽ(¬Rá‰ŒoÄ8­ˆÝ:TXÙ[<ðhÿ¾²òp'—&i‚ÎÑ.¦6-Gz¾x¾Þ5ÓGIyÛc"0zùùõÕrqž"
D$Væ‰àQýõMI½›’É(F¥V`.²+¤¯)Þ®¢ÁÑ7w«Z8ýœvÈŽ!€Ñ*PÈ^<ÿ¦™éˆs. 7V¹y>F¥ñ”B’ÂcY¿‘ƒJy¡ôÿ¾²éëjNÛE\ýè6i    #câÂB¿éUI=Ç`¯#ãZoëƒÕ–5•Ë$jÑ4sãC[hrçù\Y±«?£;úlù8ò¼±"4¥ëbl‘}ÃŽúÆI8Ò2Í6æÈ7Ûë£­S4=MH/2Ëú¦t[vGŒ¨@¥£[¦Ú»kù@èQú|òJ\Í$®Çª¼6Ð vï÷ñ­¦2²ÄåPrX9áv+éßVž"lÍ>Ïj_¶ø&ë¸ùÖ¿‰©”~æEM¹3Ÿxñz½H§U‘ÁµYÃý·ÇOU}9Ñÿ^JFH¡V»<‚ÀƒÞü}k[“ˆ¡U/¤µJ~{}yÔµ,(¢qd×k¾‘jÊQ·Ï~ƒü4ž;üÀAjcQ3 ²^5B
]Ñ5W©IQ¼–}–Xv¯·þ^™bÊ$ÛÔAU#ÍöÿËÑïv0dQØ-ð/äüñã]'ñJ]ýB¢¡”„äf€„d˜GÜ€þñÏo<k£õx—3Ò}1zR¹À\u…@Þ"V&‰¨“ÇnAøÖjc(bŒo€Eò;sßZÙQ4Þ‹ü>Q£È‰až    éÛ9eÛ~ÒnOþtc7ª¯Ó§È¾êÓ–3ýœÌQº¤}D,½ÆÒ­Áà÷ÿ‡WËÖX¤I#)}€Õñc½ýu¨Êé¶I‘kòÊÑ;~ ~“ÿo:6"ª¢ËVÒY©¸<ñþšó¥½ß¦ÔW¨·à‡IT¯´n¹àOôÐâÂ2¥Ýb\<ûGÈº<ÓÒ»+*Áœ;p+hù½y'vŒH!Ræ›b¿‚?©ø:½F­
›X>›7U)±Ówê1Å´±&¾¤Ö”“E
Ìœ³D‚Ù6±ûwúyÔÊŒ0Ý(
```

I just want to know what coding language this is I see alot of images that you view-source has the same or a similar language.

Comment: it is not coding language, it is binary representation of some image format

Comment: how can i process or run the binary representation of the image format ?

Answer (score 0):

You viewed the source code of an image. The source code of an image is just a bunch of gibberish to humans, though technically a human can make an image using this "language". The characters are not actually a language, they are just encoded pixels.

Comment: thanks for the information it helps alot is there an IDE can I use to process the encoded pixels?

Comment: No really, you can manually edit them in something like vscode, but you aren't going to see your changes until later, or you can download and edit the image in image editing software, but I don't think that's what you want.